# Enabling Multi-Touch/MultiClick

Tags: android

I am simply wondering how to enable multi touch when developing applications. I've googled it and these are the only things that show up

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/1763?tag=mantle_skin;content

[Multiple button presses for Android 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528160/multiple-button-presses-for-android-2-x)

I haven't had any luck with these, and it seems like the way to enable multitouch could (Might) have changed since then. All I want to do is be able to click more than one button at a time (think of a drum pad like function, for example). Thanks in advance

Comment: What is happening or not happening?

Comment: @ James Black Its not really a question of whats not happening, its a question of how do I implement this technique into a "Button multitouch"(if that makes sense). For pinch-to-zoom, the code makes sense, but for multiple clicks on different buttons, I don't know how to apply it. For instance, I want to set an OnTouchListener for "buttonA", and another one for "buttonB". All I want is for both buttons play a sound when clicked (at the same time, of course ;-)). I just don't get how this translates from pinch to zoom? I don't understand.

Comment: (CONTINUED) I wish there was a source code to do specifically what I am looking for, and even if it wasn't explained I think I could make sense of it (because, for me anyway, that's how I've leaned most effectively).

Comment: For multiple clicks on buttons you would need to write your own components as buttons aren't designed, from what I have seen, to allow that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to "enable" multi-touch. It's there ready for you write code with. My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679473/android-multi-touch-support) has an example of programming with the touch/multitouch API.